# Longtable strange formatting with macro in paragraph cell

Tags: macros, longtable

I got an unexpected behaviour with a longtable in combination with a macro. I process a string using a macro and output the result in a paragraph cell of a longtable.
In the output I see a strange spacing right in front of the macro output. I compare with manually added output from the macro, which is OK. A MWE is below.

Thanks for any advice.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.27cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xstring}

\def\address{TEST1111 TEST1111 \\ TEST222 TEST222}

\newcommand{\fixAddress}{%
    \saveexpandmode\expandarg\exploregroups
\StrSubstitute{\address}{\noexpand\\}{\newline}[\addrGlobal]%
\restoreexpandmode\addrGlobal%
}%

    \newcommand{\fixAddressE}{%
    \saveexpandmode\expandarg\exploregroups
\StrSubstitute{\address}{\noexpand\\}{\newline}[\addrGlobal]%
\restoreexpandmode%
}%

\relax
\show\address
\fixAddressE
\show\addrGlobal

\begin{document}

    \begin{longtable}[l]{@{}>{\raggedleft}p{5cm}@{\hspace{12pt}}|@{\extracolsep{12pt}}p{13cm}@{}}
    Title &\tabularnewline
    Test1 & TEST1111 TEST1111 \protect \newline   TEST222 TEST222 \tabularnewline
\textbf{Heading} & \fixAddress \tabularnewline
\textbf{Heading2} & \addrGlobal \tabularnewline 
Test2 & TEST1111 TEST1111 \protect \newline   TEST222 TEST222 \tabularnewline
Description & \begin{itemize}  \item Lorem ipsum  \item ...\end{itemize}\tabularnewline
Text & \begin{itemize}  \item Further stuff  \item ...\end{itemize}\tabularnewline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I added the output (MikTex 2.9). Note the different text start positions.
[image: Sample output]

EDIT2: \listfiles output:

```
*File List*
article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
array.sty    2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
dvips.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
utf8x.def    2004/10/17 UCS: Input encoding UTF-8
ucs.sty    2004/10/17 UCS: Unicode input support
uni-global.def    2004/10/17 UCS: Unicode global data
longtable.sty    2004/02/01 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
xstring.sty    2013/1/13  v1.7  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
ucsencs.def    2003/11/29 Fixes to fontencodings LGR, T3
omscmr.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
```

Comment: I can't spot any difference

Comment: I've got no space on my system. Can you add `\listfiles` at the top of the example and the relative output to your question? You find it in the log file starting with `File list`.

Comment: Try updating `xstring`, because mine is `2013/2/28  v1.7a`

Comment: @egreg: I had written a bug report (2012-10-20), thus the spaces problem seems to be fixed in the meantime. Next bug report is on its way, the date format should be "2013/02/28" ("YYYY/MM/DD").

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to outdated software